# MongoDb $addFields and $match

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation

In my mongodb query, I use $addFields to add ID field which concatenated of other three fields.   My problem is that I get no result if I $match that new added field with value that I want to query. For other fields, they work just fine.

[order of aggregation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh1Lu.jpg)

[what is in aggregation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2rXf.jpg)

```
data = await model.aggregate([
            {
                $project: {
                    projectName: 1,
                    price: 1,
                    'document': '$$ROOT'
                }
            },
            {
                $addFields:{
                    'document.id': {$concat: ['$document.propertyId.prefix','$document.propertyId.number']}
                }
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    $and: [
                        {
                            $or: [
                                {id: {$regex: '.*' + req.query.search + '.*', $options: "i"}},
                                {projectName: {$regex: '.*' + req.query.search + '.*', $options: "i"}},

                                /*This also doesnt work*/
                                // {'document.id': {$regex: '.*' + req.query.search + '.*', $options: "i"}},
                                // {'document.projectName': {$regex: '.*' + req.query.search + '.*', $options: "i"}},
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                $replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$document"}
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    [sortBy]: sortType
                }
            },
        ]);
```

Comment: what your data and query look like?

Comment: @Astro , i put them i parameter. You can look them up at the attached pictures

Comment: @Astro, for $project i get all the fields by using $$ROOT, then i added id field by concatenated 3 fields. After that i want to query value of that new added field.

Comment: Can you paste your code of how you add the fields and how you try to access the this field in your match? We cannot really tell from these screenshots.

Comment: @AlexP. i have attached the code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Next time please add a sample of your document so people can reproduce your problem. Having said that I don't see where your problem is. I created some data to reproduce your usecase. So I added the following document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0d5d376c9b762a7c035ec4"), 
    "projectName" : "some stack test", 
    "price" : NumberInt(45), 
    "propertyId" : {
        "prefix" : "a", 
        "number" : "7"
    }
}
```

Then I executed your script (without the sort) and it works fine:

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "projectName": 1,
            "price": 1,
            "document": '$$ROOT'
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "document.id": {
                $concat: ['$document.propertyId.prefix', '$document.propertyId.number']
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [{
                $or: [{
                        "projectName": {
                            $regex: '.*' + "some stack test"
                        }
                    },

                    {
                        "document.id": {
                            $regex: '.*' + "a" + '.*',
                            $options: "7"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }]

        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$document"
        }
    }
])
```

The fact that you get no results is probably due to your request parameters. Besides how can the `"projectName"`have the same search parameters as your `"document.id"` Do they even match?
Check your match pipeline again:

```
{"projectName": {$regex: '.*' + req.query.search + '.*', $options: "i"}},       
{'document.id': {$regex: '.*' + req.query.search + '.*', $options: "i"}}
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Somehow there is an invisible space in my parameter although i didn't pass them that way.
They have the same search parameter because i want to search a certain text whether it exist in any of the fields.
Thanks