# MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline: $match with expression not possible?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm doing a rather complicated aggregation pipeline and have a rather strange phenomenon - I extracted a short example to visualize my problem here.

It seemed related to [MongoDb $addFields and $match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47309861/mongodb-addfields-and-match) - but it doesn't contain any information for me to fix the problem at hand.

**Note**: Please note that my problem is not with the specific example of using date fields and or dealing with values, the problem is that I'm not able to `$match` using an expression - using a field that was added before with `$addFields` or not.

Given MongoDB: 3.6.3 (currently latest)

Let's insert some testdata:

```
db.testexample.insert({
   "dateField": new ISODate("2016-05-18T16:00:00Z")
});

db.testexample.insert({
   "dateField": new ISODate("2018-05-18T16:00:00Z")
});
```

Now let's make simple pipeline that computes only the year of the date and $matches on that:

```
db.testexample.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "dateFieldYear": {"$year": "$dateField"}
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "dateFieldYear": {"$eq": "$dateFieldYear"}}
        }
    }
])
```

--> No matches

It should match as it's the same field? Maybe with more trickery (using an `$add`)?

```
db.testexample.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "dateFieldYear": {"$year": "$dateField"}
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "dateFieldYear": {"$eq": {"$add": ["$dateFieldYear", 0]}}
        }
    }
])
```

--> No matches

Still no dice.. Next i thought that variables altogether are a problem. So let's fix the values:

```
db.testexample.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "dateFieldYear": {"$year": "$dateField"}
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "dateFieldYear": {"$eq": {"$add": [2016, 0]}}
        }
    }
])
```

--> No matches

Wait.. something is really wrong here.. Let's see with a static value:

```
db.testexample.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "dateFieldYear": {"$year": "$dateField"}
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "dateFieldYear": 2016
        }
    }
])
```

--> 1 record found!

**So my conclusion** seems to be that *`$match` cannot take an expression on a field in an aggregate pipeline*. But this doesn't seem possible - as the documentation states that `$match` follows the query syntax [as described here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/).

Anybody can help how it can be done to `$match` using the simple example `"dateFieldYear": {"$eq": "$dateFieldYear"}}` - why doesn't this work as expected?

Thanks so much for any help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) ( 3.6 mongo version operator ) to use aggregation functions in regular query.

Compare [`query operators`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) vs [`aggregation comparison operators`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-comparison/).

In your case

```
db.testexample.find({$expr:{$eq:["$dateFieldYear", "$dateFieldYear"]}})
```

Regular Query:

```
db.testexample.find({$expr:{$eq:["$dateFieldYear", {"$year": "$dateField"}]}})
```

Aggregation Query:

```
db.testexample.aggregate({$match:{$expr:{$eq:["$dateFieldYear", {"$year": "$dateField"}]}})
```

Comment: Aaaah yes.. As soon as I posted the question, i've seen $expr in the documentation ;-).. Should haved looked more closely.. Thanks

Comment: Is there any wat we can apply 2 conditions in $expr?  I mean if date match vand and the status?

Comment: @KishorPatidar See the $and operator